# How to run a swarm in Docker?

Tags: docker-swarm

I'm new to Docker and I'm doing the Get-Started part of the documentation, but I got stuck in step 4, I do not make mistakes when doing this step, but when I enter the ip 192.168.99.100 it does not show me anything. I hope you can help me THANK YOU.[docker info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tc9E.png)

Comment: This is an [English-only site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) ([official policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/)). Please ask your question in English, or ask at [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Angel, I do not know which step or docs you're talking about (adding links would help a lot), but there's only one way to start a Docker Swarm

`docker swarm init`

You may also specify the IP of the machine you're starting the swarm in if it has more than one network interface:

`docker swarm init --advertise-addr <ip-where-you-want-the-node-to-listen-to-swarm-events>`

I would really recommend you do not use docker toolbox, instead use [Play With Docker](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/), where you'll be able to spawn nodes and try stuff around without needing to configure anything.